# No puedo usar una imagen personalizada en JOptionPane.MessageDialog

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy trabajando un conversor de unidades de temperatura en java, donde quiero cambiar la imagen por defecto del message dialog de JOptionPane.

Al intentarlo me da el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.(ImageIcon.java:217)
> at cl.uach.info090.actividad1.TemperatureConversor.conversor(TemperatureConversor.java:32)
> at cl.uach.info090.actividad1.TemperatureConversor.main(TemperatureConversor.java:26)

El trozo de código donde busco cambiar la imagen por defecto es el siguiente:

```
if (medida == 'c' || medida == 'C') {
   double kelvin = numero+273.15;
   float fahrenheit = (numero * 9/5) + 32;
   Icon termometro = new ImageIcon(TemperatureConversor.class.getResource("/Actividad1_AndresTorres/src/cl/uach/info090/actividad1/termometro.png"));
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
           null, "Kelvin = "+ kelvin +"°K"+"\n"+"Fahrenheit = "+ fahrenheit +"°F", input, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, termometro);
}
```

Comment: relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/405955/c%c3%b3mo-a%c3%b1adir-una-imagen-a-un-label PD: Ya intentaste sin la barra inicial?

Answer (score 0):

Me pasó lo mismo, tu problema tiene que ver con la URL de tu directorio

Diría que la URL para generar el ícono sería la siguiente:

> /cl/uach/info090/actividad1/termometro.png

No hay necesidad de agregar el nombre de tu proyecto ni la carpeta "*src*", esto según el caso.

Answer (score 0):

A mí me sirvió mover la carpeta de imágenes a la siguiente carpeta:

```
[nameApp]/target/classes/
```

Lo descubrí imprimiendo la dirección desde donde iniciaba getResource( ) :

```
System.out.println("URL: "+getClass().getResource(""));
```

> URL: file:/D:/ . . . /[nameApp]/target/classes/