# maven: Cómo añadir una imagen a un label?

Tags: java, netbeans, imagen, java-swing, maven

Tengo un problema con apache netbeans-12 en el momento de añadir una imagen a un label,
cuando ejecuto mi programa me aparece el siguiente error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at clases.ejemplo.initComponents(ejemplo.java:34)
    at clases.ejemplo.<init>(ejemplo.java:18)
    at clases.ejemplo$1.run(ejemplo.java:87)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Si estoy creando mi paquete y ahi estan mis imagenes, la forma en que agrego la imagen es de manera directa, es decir me voy a las propiedades le doy icon , selecciono mi paquete y la imagen, por lo que no se cual seria el problema.

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/clases/imagen/insta.png"))); // NOI18N
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: SUgerencia; Evitar las mayúsculas sostenidas. De paso, el título debe resulmir tu pregunta/problema, en vez de tener una colección de keywords que no dicen nada (para eso son las etiquetas!). Por otra parte, podrías añadir  a tu pregunta algo más de tu código? Digamos, cómo defines jLabel1, qué librerías importas, algo más de ejemplo.java... Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta

Comment: El error se da antes, como lo dice la traza en `at clases.ejemplo.initComponents(ejemplo.java:34)`. Así pues, por favor, de nuevo, edita la pregunta y añade más de tu clase ejemplo para ver qué haces al inicializar.

Comment: cuando creas el proyecto crealo en> java with ant, ahi ya no tendras ese problema, si lo creas con java with maven da ese error

Comment: Estoy teniendo el mismo problema. Estoy usando la sección "Design" para hacer el JPanel, y para agregar imágenes, estoy usando una Label y colocando un Icon. Aunque no escribo una línea de código, siempre tengo este error cuando uso una imagen existente en el proyecto. Este mismo error no ocurre cuando se usa un directorio externo. Creo que puede ser un problema con la versión de Apache NetBeans, considerando que **en la versión 12.0 JFrames ni siquiera se ejecutó**. Estoy usando la versión 12.2. (Estoy usando Google Translate porque mi idioma principal es el portugues, lo siento por los error

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cargar imágen con maven da NPE ( Couldn't find file )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/273988/cargar-im%c3%a1gen-con-maven-da-npe-couldnt-find-file)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que por algún motivo Netbeans necesita que crees la carpeta *resources* y en esta carpeta crear los paquetes que contendrán tus imágenes o recursos, por lo que el primer paso para solucionar este problema sería crear la carpeta.

Entonces, para hacerlo, tienes que dirigirte al apartado *Files* en la barra de navegación, después tienes que desplegar las carpetas hasta llegar al *main*, ahí tienes que crear la carpeta *resources* y pegar tus imágenes ahí.

Puedes simplemente añadirlas sobreponiendo las imágenes en el folder.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez hecho esto tienes que volver al apartado *proyects*, en el cual se habrá añadido una carpeta llamada *Other Sources*: en esta tendrás que crear un Java package con el nombre que le quieres dar a ese apartado de recursos, en mi ejemplo le puse *images*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez creado el paquete *images* le añadí imágenes.

Puedes simplemente añadirlas sobreponiendo las imágenes en el paquete y soltándolas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente ahora sí puedes añadir las imágenes que quieras a tus jLabels, solo asegúrate que se estén añadiendo del paquete que acabas de crear en *Other resources*.

Answer (score -1):

Me parece que el problema se debe a que la imagen no existe o el path es incorrecto, debes asegurar que tu imagen se encuentre aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es una forma de cargar la imagen, por cierto, te sugiero validar si la imagen existe:

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon("/clases/imagen/insta.png");                
if(icon != null){
    //Agrega Icono
    jLabel1.setIcon(icon);
}else{
    //No existe imagen.
}
```

Comment: si ahi se encuentra

Comment: Pero carga la imagen como lo indico en mi respuesta.

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque tu respuesta es totalmente incorrecta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2912), en concreto el tipo de proyecto del OP es maven, no JavaFX